# Gravity Forms JS gets removed on AJAX submit fail

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

To replicate my issue:

Create a from with gravity forms Wordpress plugin and enable AJAX submit for it.

Next, add some modification to the form with JS, in my case i am doing this to my select fields:

```
$('select').wrap('<div class="select-wrapper"></div>');
```

Make the select field a required input when creating your form, then go ahead and submit the form without filling it, all JS gets removed on form submit via AJAX fail.

Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you wrap your JS inside this.

There is hook provided `gform_post_render`

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(){

   $('select').wrap('<div class="select-wrapper"></div>');

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any JS related error. Can you try to alert in bind event ?

Comment: Which jQuery and Wordpress version are you using ?

Comment: WP 4.7.1 i believe this WP version is using jQuery 3.1.1 - I remember  I have used your solution a long time ago before i was using Webpack to bundle my scripts in my themes. Maybe my build is somehow interfering.